# Returning array (pointer) of 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays

A function dynamically creates an `int` array whose elements are predetermined to be `int[2]`. Is there any way to have a function assign values to that array and then return it to the caller.

The below code accomplishes this task but throws warning: `initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int *get_values()
{
    int (*x)[2] = malloc(sizeof(int[2])*3);

    x[0][0] = 1;
    x[0][1] = 2;

    x[1][0] = 11;
    x[1][1] = 12;

    x[2][0] = 21;
    x[2][1] = 22;

    return x;   
}

int main()
{
    int (*x)[2] = get_values();

    int i;
    for (i=0; i!=3; i++)
        printf("x[%d] = { %d, %d }\n", i, x[i][0], x[i][1]);
}
```

I'm aware of the alternative where you dynamically allocate both dimensions, but this is something that I am curious about.

Comment: Why don't you declare the correct function return type?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Maybe because he doesn't know how to put it in the prototype ;) The correct prototype for your function should be `int (*get_values())[2] { ... }`.

Comment: I wasn't quite sure either and wanted to check first. But "how do I declare..." was not what the OP asked ;-).

Comment: Btw, I think it's fine to simply cast the pointers around as needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than keep repeating the same clunky syntax it can be helpful to define a typedef in cases like this. This makes it easier to declare the correct return type for `get_values`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int I2[2];

I2 * get_values(void)
{
    I2 * x = malloc(sizeof(I2) * 3);

    x[0][0] = 1;
    x[0][1] = 2;

    x[1][0] = 11;
    x[1][1] = 12;

    x[2][0] = 21;
    x[2][1] = 22;

    return x;   
}

int main()
{
    I2 * x = get_values();

    int i;
    for (i=0; i!=3; i++)
        printf("x[%d] = { %d, %d }\n", i, x[i][0], x[i][1]);

    free(x);
}
```

<kbd>[LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/BwmDhv)</kbd>

Recommended reading: [Don't repeat yourself (DRY)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 4):

And this is how it looks without a typedef:

```
int (*get_values(void))[2]
{  
    return NULL;   
}
```

Pretty unreadable.

Notice in that function definition, if you replace `get_values(void)` with x you get: `int (*x)[2]`, which is exactly what the pointer definition looks like.

Comment: Now declare a function taking an array pointer as parameter, returning an array pointer :)

Comment: @Lundin That is too easy, just replace void with the array pointer, the rest is the same.

Comment: The `2` isn't required, is it?

Comment: @CoolGuy 2 is required.

Comment: @2501 But it compiles for me without any warnings when omitting the `2` (GCC).

Comment: @CoolGuy Apparently in this case you can omit the 2, however if the returned type doesn't match with the assigned type, the behavior is undefined. Omitting the size also removes warnings that will warn you about the type discrepancy. In any case, there is no good reason to omit it, even you if are allowed to.

Comment: @2501 Yeah `int(*get_values((int*)[2]))[2]` is totally trivial reading :)

Comment: @CoolGuy I'm wondering what meaning gcc bestows on `int (*get_values(void))[]`. In particular, what value it thinks `get_values()+1` should have then.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider It is a pointer to an incomplete type. It can't be dereferenced. I'm not sure if `int(*)[]` is compatible with `int(*)[2]`, but gcc thinks it is.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Apparently this `int(*)[]` is a composite type, see: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.2.7.

Comment: @2501 Looks to me as if it's just an incomplete type (as you said first) which is compatible with the (complete) type of `x`. (A "composite type" by contrast is, as I read it, the result of *two declarations for the same entity*, as in the example 6.2.7/f in n1570.) In order to determine compatibility we read 6.7.6.2/6: "For two array types to be compatible, [..]  if both size specifiers are present, [...] then both size
specifiers shall have the same constant value." This appears to implicate that one size specifier can be missing for compatible arrays. (ctd.)

Comment: (... ctd.) The issue is slightly more complex because actually we are dealing with a function declaration, but I think in this context the rules for compatibility of array types apply to declarations of function return types (and thus are part of a function declaration). Ah, and last not least we are concerned with pointers to array, not arrays proper, but I'm sure that the standard says somewhere that pointer types are compatible if the types pointed to are compatible... (I'm glad I don't have to write documents that are scrutinized this way...).

Comment: (...ctd.) And as a *post scriptum*, gcc correctly balks if I try to write `int (*get_values())[]; get_values()+1;`: "invalid use of array with unspecified bounds".